# How to differentiate between a parser and lexer rule in the following?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

Sometimes I get a bit confused between a lexing rule vs. a parsing rule, and there's been a nice thread on it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170518183925/https://www.3dbuzz.com/forum/threads/203932-ANTLR-When-to-use-Parser-Rules-vs-Lexer-Rules). For example in the following:

```
value
    : string CAST_OPERATOR type
    ;

string
    : S_QUOTE STRING_VALUE S_QUOTE
    ;

# <-- what is this?
type
    : 'date' | 'string' 
    ;

STRING_VALUE
    : [a-zA-Z0-9-]+
    ;

CAST_OPERATOR
    : '::'
    ;
```

For the `type` -- this is either the string (or character stream) `date` or `string`. Should that be a lexing rule or a parsing rule? I suppose I could break it down even more into:

```
type
    : DATE_TYPE | STRING_TYPE
    ;

DATE_TYPE
    : 'date'
    ;

STRING_TYPE
    : 'string'
    ;
```

But still I'm not quite sure which of the above is preferable, and why it would be so. The first two rules -- `value` and `string` seem clear to me to be parsing rules -- and the last two rules -- `STRING_VALUE` and `CAST_OPERATOR` seem clear to me to be lexing rules (only by intuition though, I could not give a proper explanation). So why would the `type` be one way or the other?

Literally the only practical difference I've found is that a lexing rule can include a character class and a parsing rule cannot.

---

**Update**: I suppose another thing is a lexing rule is terminal, it won't provide any subdivision of parts. For example in the following we can break down `$55` into `$` and `55`:

[image]

But if we set the `cost` as a lexing rule, it will not break it down any further:

[image]

So basically a lexing rule is atomic and terminal, whereas a parsing rule is more like a molecule that consists of various parts (atoms) that can be seen within it. Is that a good description/understanding of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Update" is on the right track.  That's a definite distinction.

You also need to understand the ANTLR pipeline.  I.e. that the stream of characters is processed by the Lexer rules to produce a stream of tokens (atoms, in you analogy).  It does not do that with recursive descent rule matching, but rather attempts to match you input against all of the Lexer rules. Where:

- The rule that matches the longest sequence of input characters will "win"
- In the event that multiple Lexer rules match the same length character sequence, then the rule that occurs first will "win"

Once you've got you stream of "atoms" (aka `Tokens`), then ANTLR uses the parser rules (recursively from the start rule) to try to match sequences of tokens.